# Win32: VirtualAllocEx get access denied for process created using CreateProcessAsUser

Tags: windows, winapi, process, access-denied

I have a process I created using `CreateProcessAsUser()` and I've opened a new handle to it using:

```
HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
```

This call succeeds and I get a handle to the process. When I try to use this handle to do

```
VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, pbAddress, cbAlloc, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE)
```

it fails with ACCESS_DENIED (5), even though the handle I'm using has `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`
This also fails with the process handle I get back from the call to `CreateProcessAsUser`
When I'm creating the process using the normal `CreateProcess()` it works fine.

What could cause this behavior?
My process already has `SeDebugPrivilege` so that's not it.

What I'm trying to do is to use Detours to inject a dll to a new process. With the normal CreateProcess, detours works fine, but with CreateProcessAsUser I get this failure.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are leaking the process handle.  So OpenProcess() still works.  But the process isn't running anymore so VirtualAllocEx fails.

Comment: What version of the OS are you using and which version are you setting as the minimum target in the SDK?  There's a caveat about breaking changes for `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` in MSDN.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `CreateProcess...` functions return the process handle, there is no need to open the process manually.

Comment: @HansPassant nope, the process was created suspended, it's definitely still there

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy `OpenProcess` succeeds and the access right needed for `VirtualAllocEx` is documented to be `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` which is included in both versions of this constant

Comment: @RemyLebeau this fails with the handle CreateProcessAsUser returned as well

Comment: @shoosh: Which doesn't answer the question.  Which OS are you on and which are you targeting?

Comment: I'm not sure about `VirtualAllocEx`, but I know that `CreateRemoteThread` doesn't work between workstations in Windows Vista and 7. It works in Windows 8 and 8.1, though. The undocumented `NtCreateThreadEx` works on all of the above.

Comment: You didn't say what error you're getting back. My guess is that it's `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS` which means that the requested address is already in use.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I'm compiling on win7 with the SDK of VS2012 and targeting Win2008

Comment: @Paul I'm not doing anything between workstations or sessions or even desktops. Just creating a logon token and using CreateProcessAsUser

Comment: @shoosh, by default CreateProcessAsUser puts the new process in a separate workstation, so unless you've overridden this (and gone through the rigmarole necessary to give the new process access to your workstation) Paul may well be on the right track.  Also, how do you obtain the user token?  Can you show your code?  If you resume the process, does it actually launch successfully?